# Is it ok if I adjust my passport photo a bit as long as it does not affect my face?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, biometric-passports

I am in the US and I will be submitting my passport-style photo on the government website to obtain work permit to work in the US. The problem is, after one attempt, my photo was rejected by the system because of some shadow problems so I adjusted the photo a little bit by drawing a few black lines on my t-shirt and then the system accepts my passport photo right away. However, I am wondering if such adjustment is allowed? I only drew a flew black lines on my shirt which is barely noticeable.

Comment: Why didn’t you just take a new photo?

Comment: the shop where they take passport photos is too far from where I live and I don't want to pay extra money to retake the photo.

Answer (score 2):

From https://travel.state.gov/content/travel/en/us-visas/visa-information-resources/photos.html

> Photos must not be digitally enhanced or altered to change your appearance in any way.

Of course changes to just your clothing may seem innocuous, but if they detect a change there they may consider there may be other changes elsewhere.

Note that the same page says that:

> While we recommend you use a professional visa photo service to ensure your photo meets all the requirements, you may take the photo yourself.

There are links to all the requirements if you want to take that route.

An alternative may be to crop the image differently maybe? There’s a tool for that on the same page.